# How to restrict user to select only current month dates in datetimepicker control?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I want user to select only dates of the current month I don't know what should put in min and max date property.

Is there any property of something like ' current month '?

Comment: What do you think you should put into the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` fields? What about the first day of the current month in `MinDate` and the last day of the current month into `MaxDate`?

Comment: how to set first day of the month in min  and last day of the current month in max ?

Comment: See answer from @SonerGonul.

Answer (score 5):

Since both [`MinDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`MaxDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property takes `DateTime`, you can set them like;

```
DateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

DateTimePicker1.MaxDate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1))
                          .AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: This is Exactly i wanted working fine 
1 more question why my all questions are rated in negative like -1 
is it really a dumb and silly question i asked ?

Comment: @ShaikhNomanNasir: not dumb - you just appeared lazy because you didn't show us what you tried. It looked like you just wanted someone else to do your job for you, for free.

Comment: oh okay i got it now.. i'll also put what i've been keep trying to do next time thanks

Comment: @ShaikhNomanNasir I didn't vote but I think people voted your question because you can _easily_ find your answer in a few minutes with Google. You build your logic already as _I should set `MinDate` property to first day of the current month_ and _I should set `MaxDate` property to last day of the current month_ So, the question turns into; _How can I get the first and last day of the current month?_ In a few second search, you will find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245523/getting-the-first-and-day-of-a-month-using-a-given-datetime-instance

Comment: well thats my bad actually i've spent enough time on google but i event got some titles like first day and last day .. 
I didn't check them because i thought it will user to select only first day  and last day not other days .. 
i'm not doing argument .. i just wanted to be clear so i can avoid my dumb next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use properties MinDate and MaxDate and sets minimum and maximum dates which can be selected in control.

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
int firstDayInCurrentMonth = 1;
int lastDayInCurrentMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);

dateTimePicker.MinDate = new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, firstDayInCurrentMonth);
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, lastDayInCurrentMonth);
```

Comment: This is not how you can restrict a user from selecting dates withing the current month only.

Comment: what if current date is 12 of the month according to your code user won't be able to select 1 - 11 dates of this month ..

Comment: @QualityCatalyst there is no other way to block visible of other dates using standard DateTimePicker control. And show now difference between this answers if you know better.