# Get the first and last day of selected month and year?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 ComboBoxes on my WinForm.

```
combobox1 --> displaying months
combobox2 --> displaying  years
```

If I select January And 2017 It should display me something like:

```
1-wednesday
2-Thursday
.
.
.
```

till last of that month

Comment: Try something on your own first. Hint: use DateTime.DaysInMonth

Comment: First try and place your code where ever you got struggle then anyone can help you

Comment: If you are talking about this

            DateTime date = new DateTime();
   var lastDayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
            Console.WriteLine(lastDayOfMonth);

but it returns 31 ..
I want to know about the day on 31st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
//clear items
comboBox1.Items.Clear();

int month = 5;
int year = 2017;

//new datetime with specified year and month
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

//from first day of this month until first day of next month
for (int i = 0; i < (startDate.AddMonths(1) - startDate).Days; i++)
{
    //add one day to start date and add that in "number - short day name" in combobox
    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(startDate.AddDays(i).ToString("dd - ddd"));
}
```

EDIT: I forgot about `DateTime.DaysInMonth`, which can be used for even simplier solution:

```
//clear items
comboBox1.Items.Clear();

int month = 5;
int year = 2017;
//calculate how many days are in specified month
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

//loop through all days in month
for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
{
    //add one day to start date and add that in "number - short day name" in combobox
    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(new DateTime(year, month, i).ToString("dd - ddd"));
}
```

Comment: one word--  Perfect (Y)

Comment: @Ivar it's the same because the condition part of `for` is not calculated with every iteration but only once.

Comment: @Ivar ooops, you're right! Thanks for noticing. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` structure stores only one value, not range of values. `MinValue` and `MaxValue` are static fields, which hold range of possible values for instances of `DateTime` structure. These fields are static and does not relate to particular instance of `DateTime`. They relate to `DateTime` type itself.

```
DateTime date = ...
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245523/getting-the-first-and-last-day-of-a-month-using-a-given-datetime-object)