# how to find out is it a new month

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a notification whenever it is the 1st day of every month but I am having errors at the current moment.

The error I face is that every last day of the same month it keeps stating that is is a new month which is not the result I am expecting

I will put my code here

```
DateTime firstDayOfnextMonth = new DateTime(
     DateTime.Today.Year, 
     DateTime.Today.Month,
     DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month));

if (DateTime.Today == firstDayOfnextMonth)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Its a new month");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Its old month");
}
```

[image: Error img]

Comment: The name of "last day of the current month" variable you have is very strange - `firstDayOfnextMonth`... You may want to re-read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245523/getting-the-first-and-last-day-of-a-month-using-a-given-datetime-object to clarify what you are doing to yourself.

Comment: Your question sounds weird since first day of the next month can never be today.

Answer (score 7):

You can do trigger notification by start date of every months as its always start with day 1.

I hope this will help you.

```
        if (DateTime.Now.Day == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its a new month");
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Its old month");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down this code:

```
DateTime firstDayOfnextMonth = new DateTime(
     DateTime.Today.Year, 
     DateTime.Today.Month,
     DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month));
```

For today's date, DateTime.Today will return `2018/11/30`. Thus, `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` will return 30.

Constructing a DateTime with year 2018, month 11, and date 30 will, of course create a date object representing `2018/11/30`, not `2018/12/01` as you seem to expect.

As AGH said in their answer, you should simply check if `DateTime.Now.Day == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still looking for the first day of the next month you can try the following approach:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2018, 12, 20);//or DateTime.Today...
DateTime firstDayOfnextMonth = new DateTime(d.Year + (d.Month) / 12, (d.Month) % 12 + 1, 1);
```